# manipulating string if string starts with specific characters pyspark

Tags: pyspark, substring

I have this dataframe with a column of strings:

| Column A |
| --- |
| AB-001-1-12345-A |
| AB-001-1-12346-B |
| ABC012345B |
| ABC012346B |

In PySpark, I want to create a new column where if there is "AB-" in front, the new column remove the characters "AB-" and keep the rest of the characters. Otherwise, the strings should remain the same.

Expected Output:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| AB-001-1-12345-A | 001-1-12345-A |
| AB-001-1-12346-B | 001-1-12346-B |
| ABC012345B | ABC012345B |
| ABC012346B | ABC012346B |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works for you

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.withColumn("col_b",when(col("col_a").startswith("AB-") , split(col("col_a"),"AB-").getItem(1)).otherwise(col("col_a")))
df.show()
```

Output

```
+----------------+-------------+
|           col_a|        col_b|
+----------------+-------------+
|AB-001-1-12345-A|001-1-12345-A|
|AB-001-1-12346-B|001-1-12346-B|
|      ABC012345B|   ABC012345B|
|      ABC012346B|   ABC012346B|
+----------------+-------------+
```